# Strings, arrays and their assignment vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, variable-assignment

Here is what I am trying to but VB doesn't like it, is what I am trying here possible or should I try another route?

```
Dim mystringarray() As String = If(trueorfalse, {"TrueString"}, {"List", "Of", "Other", "Strings"})
```

Description of the errors are
Expression expected.
for the first and second {
and finally
Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.
at the last }

.net framework 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008

What I was looking for was the New String() {"TrueString"} syntax which worked fine

But the above syntax works fine under VS Express 2013

Comment: What do you mean *VB doesn't like it*? Your code worked fine for me..

Comment: If there's an error then there's an error message.  ALWAYS provide that error message, even if you don't think we need it.

Comment: What .net framework you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using older version of .Net Framework like 2.0 then simple `If` operator will not work in that case. You have to use `If Then Else End IF` or you can use `IIf` method for single line result.

You can do like this also.

```
Dim bValue As Boolean = False
Dim mystringarray() As String = IIf(bValue, New String() {"TrueString"}, New String() {"List", "Of", "Other", "Strings"})
```

Comment: How does introducing the `IIf` operator help answer this question?

Comment: if OP is using older version of .net framework then `if` operator will not work. that's why i have suggested this solution and OP has just mentioned that *VB doesn't like it*.

Comment: I think that assumption should be explicitly stated in your answer. Then it would be a very good answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity: as opposed to the If-operator(conditional-operator) IIf is just a method. Just nitpicking ;) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/03/11/if-operator-a-new-and-improved-iif-sophia-salim.aspx

Comment: @shell: with option strict that doesnt compile, does it? IIf is not strongly typed that means that you  always have to cast it from object to the correct type. It is also worth mentioning that it has no short-circuiting capabilities, so both sides are evaluated regardless of the bValue value. In. NET 1.1 times i've found IIf pretty useless in most cases.

Comment: exactly @TimSchmelter with the `Option Strict On` it could not be compiled. we have to cast it to `String()` always. So, i think it is better to use simple `If The Else End If` operator instead of `IIf` method.